# Sequentially label index to duplicate DataFrame index

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([100,200,300], [1,1,2])

     0
1  100
1  200
2  300
```

I want to add a second-level index (MultiIndex) so it looks like this:

```
           0
index i2     
1     0  100
      1  200
2     0  300
```

That is, I want the second-level index (here called `i2`) to be zero where `df.duplicated()` is False (meaning the index is not the same as the one above), and to be a sequential number for other rows.

The general idea is to take an index which has duplicates and make it no longer have duplicates by introducing an additional index level which starts from zero and increments only as needed to keep the full index unique for each row.

The solution should use NumPy or Pandas functions, and not Python loops, i.e. it should be vectorized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) (working with `Series` or `DataFrame`, so [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) or `Series` constructor first) with [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
s = df.index.to_series()
#alternative solution
#s = pd.Series(df.index)
s = s.groupby(s).cumcount()
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index, s], names=['index','i2'])
print (df)
            0
index i2     
1     0   100
      1   200
2     0   300
```

Thank you [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408952/sequentially-label-index-to-duplicate-dataframe-index/45408971?noredirect=1#comment77780421_45408971):

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index, df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()],
                                     names=['index','i2'])

print (df)
            0
index i2     
1     0   100
      1   200
2     0   300
```

---

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index, df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()],
                                     names=['index','i2'])
print (df)
            0
index i2     
1     0   100
      1   200
2     0   300
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  Though `s.groupby(s)` does look silly!

Comment: `df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index, df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()], names=['index','i2'])` would do too, without needing intermediate `s`.